# Modify a file date using batch / Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm currently having issue to find a way to create a small batch which will rename all the file of a specific folder. Here's an example :

ID32432 - Name of the file - 31.01.2014

I'm trying to create a batch which is able to modify 31.01.2014 by 31.01.2015
Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks in advance. !

PS: Does anyone know how i could add a regex to my powershell in order to make sure i'm replacing this type of date ? dd.mm.yyyy

Then i would like to increment yyyy + 1. This should look like this i guess : `"\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}"`

Here's my initial powershell code :

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "2014","2015" }
```

Comment: so you want to increment the year? Is the year always at the end of the file name?

Comment: Yeah i wanna increment the year.

By the way the date is not always at the end but always delimited by "."

Comment: then is the date always the third delimited part (by `-`).I need a more specific pattern to get the date.

Comment: No the date basicelly can be everywhere. The only thing is that it's always "dd.mm.yyyy" format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with PowerShell then you can get this done using a simple `PowerShell` command like below. It will replace `2014` with `2015` for all files inside that folder/directory.

`cd` to the specific directory like `cd D:\Testing`

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "2014","2015" }
```

Not exactly by default but can be done something close

Create a file with below code snippet and save it as `test.ps1` [any naming to that matter]

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $path = $null
)

cd $path;

Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "2014","2015" };
```

It's now a PowerShell script which can be run from PowerShell command prompt like below where `D:\Testing` is nothing but the command line argument (A mandatory parameter to be passed to the script else script will fail)

```
.\test.ps1 D:\Testing
```

Now, you can easily set this script in Windows Task Scheduler and have it run on a specific time based on your need.

Comment: Basicelly i would rather use a batch file so i don't have to use powershell each time i'm wanna renamemy files

Comment: For any purpose, if you can use a batch script then you can as well use powershell script. Anyways, it's your choice.

Comment: Is there anyway to execute this command by default in the folder in which the script is ?

Comment: By default? NO but can be scheduled. See edited answer, if that helps.

Comment: Thx a lot dude.

Now i just need to find a way to make sure i'm not just modifying 2014 by 2015 by finding a regex which could find this format : "dd.mm.yyyy"

Comment: Any idea about how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

with pure batch (assuming you have or you are able to get the file name):

```
@echo off

set "the_file=ID32432 - Name of the file - 31.01.2014.ext"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=." %%A in ("%the_file%") do (
    set year_part=%%C
    set year_=!year_part:~0,4!
    set rest_=!year_part:~4!
    set /a year_inc_=year_+1
    set new_name=%%A%%B!year_inc_!!rest_!

)
endlocal &&(
    set new_name=%new_name%
)

echo %new_name%
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help you.

```
for f in * ;do mv $f ${f/%2014/2015} ; done
```

`${f/%2014/2015}` means replace the suffix for `f`

Comment: I've created a batch file with for f in * ;do mv $f ${f/%2014/2015} ; done in it but it's not working.

Comment: This answer is for bash, not batch. They're completely different languages and this WON'T help you.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's my mistake.